# Error with custom inclusion_tag, can't find file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

I'm trying to write a custom inclusion_tag in django.

Following the example on http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

I'm just writing

```
@register.inclusion_tag('test.html')
```

where test.html is a file in the same directory ( apps/my_app/templatetags) as the .py file which defines it.

But I'm getting a

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: test.html
```

error. Which I suppose is because django can't find the template.

How could I check this? And what determines where django looks for the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates for templatetags go in the same places as those for normal views.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the included file is found by searching in the template locations defined in your settings file.

Comment: Much appreciated!